# Add a function to search on Youtube with keywords in my Discord bot [Python]

Tags: python, search, youtube, discord, bots

I am a complete beginner at Python coding for Discord. I am following some tutorials and trying to understand how things work. This music bot is just a test I am doing for myself.

I would like my bot to search music on Youtube and play it instead of taking the URL as the input. But I want to keep the URL function as well.

I understand for the Youtube search, I will need to use Youtube Api, which I am not sure how to use. Hence, I need your guidance.

Here's my code as of now:

```
async def p(self, ctx, url):
    if ctx.author.voice is None:
        await ctx.send("You are not connected to a vc!")
    voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    if ctx.voice_client is None:
        await voice_channel.connect()
    else:
        await ctx.voice_client.move_to(voice_channel)

    ctx.voice_client.stop()

    vc = ctx.voice_client

    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
        info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
        url2 = info['formats'][0]['url']
        source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(
            url2, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS)
        vc.play(source)
```

I would be glad if someone can help me out!

Thanks!

Comment: So you mean search by name and URL?

Comment: Mostly users will search by name. So that is primary requirement. But I want to keep the URL as well. So search by both name and URL. 

For eg: ?p music chill 
?p <some url>

Both should work.